# Docker log (driver json-file) location for Docker for windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I want to locate a container's log location.

- I use **Docker Desktop for Windows**
- I know that on linux they are at `/var/lib/docker/containers/`

But where is it. Is it hidden away somewhere in an inaccessible VM?

Comment: Which version of Docker Desktop for Windows do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows you can find the containers logs inside:

```
C:\ProgramData\docker\containers\[Your_container_ID]\[Your_container_ID]-json.log
```

Comment: Which version of Docker Desktop for Windows do you use? For Docker Desktop 2.2.0.4, I can't find out the folders like you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 10 + WSL 2  (Ubuntu 20.04), Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61

[Logging Driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/)

```
docker info --format '{{.LoggingDriver}}'
'json-file'
```

[Docker Inspect LogPath](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/)

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <Some_Container_id>
'/var/lib/docker/containers/bb69ae7df957c5f8c8b6d63372aa9cf9b94fa6ef0e44ccecbccb6d190baadb51/bb69ae7df957c5f8c8b6d63372aa9cf9b94fa6ef0e44ccecbccb6d190baadb51-json.log'
```

Docker Artifacts are stored in following location

`DOCKER_ARTIFACTS == \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker`

[image]

Location of container logs

`DOCKER_ARTIFACTS\containers\[Your_container_ID]\[Your_container_ID]-json.log`

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: thanks - just a quick note for a licensed v4.24.2: I see them in subdirectories of \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\containers

Answer (score 0):

For windows , the container storage is the Hyper V's virtual Hard disk.You would have to connect to that hard disk to get the container logs.

See this lonk for more details :https://forums.docker.com/t/where-are-images-stored/9794/7

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, on Windows 10 these logs are now located at

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\containers
```

but knowing Docker this could well have changed by the time you read this!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11, You can find the directories with container ids in this path,

```
\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\containers
```

There, you have `<container id>.log` file which is what you want.