# Docker logs command doesn't show any logs

Tags: docker, flask

I have a flask app in python which is built into an image , when I try to run it using the command

`docker logs -f f7e2cd41c0706b7a26d9ff5821aa1d792c685826d1c9707422a2a5dfa2e33796`

It is not showing any logs , it should at least show that flask app has started right ? Note that I am able to hit the flask API from the host and it is working.There are many print statements in the code for this API to have worked , so **those print statements should have come in the logs**. Am I missing something here ?

Dockerfile is :

```
FROM python:3.6.8

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

#RUN apt-get update -y
#RUN apt-get install python-pip -y

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5001

WORKDIR Flask/
RUN chmod -x main.py ;

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Comment: Hello Ktwradr,  which image you have used please let me know, how to reproduce your scenario? I assume that the log file is not set properly to get the stdout of your server logs

Comment: I have python 3.6 as the base image

Comment: Does [setting `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering/107717#107717) help?  (If you wait long enough does it produce a chunk of output?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get logs from your host machine. The default logging driver is a JSON-structured file located on local disk

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/[container-id]/[container-id]-json. log.
```

Or the same way as you did will also work.

```
 sudo docker ps -a
 sudo docker logs -f container-id
```

Comment: i'm using windows any idea where it'll be stored in windows

Comment: @Kitwradr Sorry i have no idea in windows but you do the second step i have mentioned that will work.

Comment: @Kitwradr `docker inspect [container-id] | findstr "LogPath"` should provide you the log path.

Comment: The path I got was ```/var/lib/docker/containers/f7e2cd41c0706b7a26d9ff5821aa1d792c685826d1c9707422a2a5dfa2e33796/f7e2cd41c0706b7a26d9ff5821aa1d792c685826d1c9707422a2a5dfa2e33796-json.log``` , but var/lib ? Where is this in windows  ? @Nitish

Comment: @kitwradr have a look at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219225/docker-log-driver-json-file-location-for-docker-for-windows) post

Comment: in my case docker inspect on ui it shows LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/. but when i do cd into lib directory there is no docker directory

Answer (score 0):

For windows wsl backend Users, the default logging driver is located on

`\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\containers[container-id]\[container-id]-json.log.`

[image: the Directory in Explorer]