# Problem on send logs of console with Open Telemetry to elastic search on deploy in a container app

Tags: .net, azure, open-telemetry, azure-container-apps

I have a application in .net 6. I install the auto instrumentation of open telemetry based on this tutorial:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/auto-instrumentation-of-net-applications-opentelemetry

I create my enviroment variable with the process on create the container and they correct defined
My endpoint of elastic that they provide in the elastic in a port 443 and my application (with the dockerFile is in 5000 port) and the container also in the 5000

In local enviroment I can run the application and the elatic receive logs of console and traces
But when I push my code and deploy in a container app of azure I can seed traces of request to elastic, but I can't send logs of console and the console not show any error

The code of my automatic instrumentation:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

# Installing OpenTelemetry
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip curl
RUN mkdir /otel
RUN curl -L -o /otel/otel-dotnet-install.sh https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-instrumentation/releases/download/v1.1.0/otel-dotnet-auto-install.sh
RUN chmod +x /otel/otel-dotnet-install.sh

# Configure OpenTelemetry
ENV OTEL_DOTNET_AUTO_HOME=/otel
RUN /bin/bash /otel/otel-dotnet-install.sh

ENV OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER="otlp"
ENV OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER="otlp"
ENV OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER="otlp"

# Additional configuration
RUN chmod +x /otel/instrument.sh
COPY platform-detection.sh /otel/
RUN chmod +x /otel/platform-detection.sh && /otel/platform-detection.sh
```

The code of my application:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Base image setup
FROM open-telemetry-instrumentation-dotnet-6:latest AS base #this image i create with the code above
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL=http/protobuf
ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_HEADERS=Authorization=Bearer Token
ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=https://nameoftheendpoint.apm.westus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:443
ENV OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name=ApiTest,deployment.environment=development,service.version=1.0.0
ENV OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=ApiTest

#Building the .NET application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["./ApiTest/ApiTest.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./ApiTest.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./ApiTest/ApiTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

#Publishing the application
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "./ApiTest/ApiTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

#Preparing the final image
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

#Entry point setup and run instrumentation for .NET
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /otel/instrument.sh && dotnet ApiTest.dll"]
```

I want to use the automatic instrumentation in a container app of the azure and send logs of console and traces to elastic APM

Comment: Keep in mind that in Development mode, the logs will be different to production mode, so there's a chance there just aren't any logs being emitted. To test that, have an exception thrown and see if you see that.

Answer (score 0):

- By default, `docker logs` or `docker service logs` display the command's output just as it would appear if you ran the command interactively in a terminal. When using a [logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) that sends logs to a file, an external host, a database, or another logging back-end with ["dual logging"](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/dual-logging/) disabled, `docker logs` may not show useful [information](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/).
- Refer to the Docker log location for Docker for [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219225/docker-log-driver-json-file-location-for-docker-for-windows).
- Add the following to `appsettings.json`:

```json
 "Console": {
      "IncludeScopes": true
    }
```

**Added the config to the logging service:**

```
            services.AddLogging(builder =>
                builder
                    .AddDebug()
                    .AddConsole()
                    .AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
                    .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information)
            );
```

**Docker:**

```
FROM ${ARCH}mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0. AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-preview AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["login.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./login.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet add package Elastic.Apm --version 1.22.0
RUN dotnet build "login.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "login.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENV ELASTIC_APM_ENVIRONMENT=production
ENV ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN=XXX
ENV ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL=https://2a773133cd7c4cf29134d0d4a81e3ae0.apm.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:443
ENV ELASTIC_APM_SERVICE_NAME=dotnet-login-elastic-auto

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "login.dll"]
```

- Refer to visual studio ASP NET Core/.NET Core Console app logging in Docker [container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167186/asp-net-core-net-core-console-app-logging-in-docker-container).